# Извлечение данных из базы в переменную c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, firebird

Подскажите, как извлекать данные из базы данных в переменную

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, вот так(работа с MS SQL, с MySql код будет по логике такой же, но функции немного отличаться, но ваши вопросы, конечно, вам нужно научиться пояснять более подробно):

```
if (_sqlCon == null) 
{
       _sqlCon = new SqlConnection(); //создаем подключение
}
else
{
       _sqlCon.Close();
}

var sqlBuild = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder //настраиваем название сервера и БД
{
       DataSource = dateSource,
       InitialCatalog = nameBaseDate
};    
sqlBuild.IntegratedSecurity = true; //если аутентификация Windows

_sqlCon.ConnectionString = sqlBuild.ConnectionString;

 try
 {
       _sqlCon.Open(); //подключаемся
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
                //обработка ошибки подключения
 }
 var selectCommand = _sqlCon.CreateCommand(); // создаем команду для запроса
 selectCommands.CommandText = "SELECT count FROM TableName";//прописываем запрос
 var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(); //результат возвращаем в reader
 if (reader.Read()) //и считываем построчно
       count = Convert.ToInt64(readerCount[0]); //в данном примере запрос возвратил одну строку с одним столбцом - числовым значением, иначе используйте while и считывайте, пока строки не закончатся, а также при n столбцах - меняйте соответственно индекс, а также тип данных, в которфй конвертируете должен совпадать с типом столбца в БД
 reader.Close(); //закрываем reader
 _sqlCon.Close(); //закрываем соединение
```